# How to reliably set cookies on localhost using webdriver and Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In my experience, this works fine when using webdriver (via Protractor) to inject a cookie into a browser session on Firefox:

```
browser.manager().addCookie(...)
```

Where the "..." is an "httpOnly" localhost session cookie used to indicate that a user is logged in.

The same code when run against a Chrome browser (using the direct ChromeDriver) does not work.  First, there are the localhost cookie exceptions:

```
Message:
     InvalidCookieDomainError: invalid cookie domain: invalid domain:"localhost"
  (Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.89)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Linux 3.13.0-45-generic x86_64)
   Stacktrace:
     InvalidCookieDomainError: invalid cookie domain: invalid domain:"localhost"
  (Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.89)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Linux 3.13.0-45-generic x86_64)
```

Even if I can work-around the localhost problem (E.g., by setting fully qualified domain), Chrome will just ignore my changes to the cookie.

I'm running on Linux, with Protractor 2.0.0, and google-chrome 41.0.xxx and chromedriver 2.14.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two workarounds that will work with Chrome and will not break Firefox.

First, use `null` instead of `localhost` as the cookie domain.  Chrome will treat this as meaning "the same page as the current page's domain".  Which is fine, since you need to make the browser visit a page before you're allowed to set the cookies anyway.

Second, clear the existing cookie before setting the new cookie (`browser.manager().deleteCookie()`). Chrome disallows (silently) changes to some cookies via the webdriver API. By deleting the cookie, you're then allowed to set it.

```
// cookieObj is a "tough.Cookie" instance in my case
function setCookie(cookieObj) {
   var domain = cookieObj.domain;
   if (domain === 'localhost') {
      domain = null;
   }

   var mgr = browser.manage();
   var cName = cookieObj.key;

   var cookieProm = mgr.deleteCookie(cName).then(function() {
      return mgr.addCookie(
         cName,
         cookieObj.value,
         cookieObj.path,
         domain,
         cookieObj.secure,
         cookieObj.expiryTime());
   });

   cookieProm.then(function() {
      mgr.getCookie(cName).then(function(cookie) {
         console.log("Actual cookie", cName, "::", cookie);
         expect(cookie.value).toBe(cookieObj.value);
      });
   });

   return cookieProm;
}
```